# Opening docx or pdf causes Android device File read error

Tags: android, pdf, docx

I have created a App in which I am showing the **pdf** and **docx** file in Android Device which get download in device when button is been clicked we are displaying it in devices why using below code.

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FILE/a.docx");
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path,"application/msword");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(pdfIntent);
```

Getting an error message in Android 4.2:

> file read error.  File type is unsupported or the file is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct MIME type for DOCX files. That is the MIME type for the older DOC format. Try `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.

Also, do not use concatenation to build file paths, as you are making assumptions about the value returned by `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Use:

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "FILE/a.docx");
```